# Can you restore specific applications from a Time Machine backup?

Tags: mac, backup, time-machine, restore

I'm about to format and re-install snow leopard on my mac, and after the fresh install i want to restore some stuff from my time machine backup.

I dont want to restore all of my applications, only some specific ones. Yet when i go to migration assistant there is only an option for all applications.

Any help?

Comment: When I try it, I don't see any options to backup specific files... Only my HDD. I can only chose my Time Machine and my destination HDD. No specific folders or anything...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't restore the applications in the Migration Assistant  you can restore them later by navigating to the /Applications folder and then running "Time Machine.app"  go to the point in your history you want to restore and the choose the apps you want.

Good Luck.